# how to solve (2/2) ErrorException View [dashboard] not found in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in LARAVEL (laravale 5.4).

**web.php is:**

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('method1.home');
});
```

**home.blade.php is:**

```
@extends('dashboard')
```

**dashboard.blade.php is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
@include('includes.head')

</head>

<body>

do something...
</body>
```

path and folder name is correct.

BUt I got error:

(2/2) ErrorException
View [dashboard] not found. (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\admin_laravel\resources\views\method1\home.blade.php)

Comment: Where is `dashboard.blade.php` located? In the folder `method1`?

Comment: Same folder in method1 where home.blade.php is located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dashboard.blade.php` is located in `resources/views/method1/` you need to change your `@extends` statement to include that folder:

```
@extends('dashboard')
```

should be

```
@extends('method1.dashboard')
```

Comment: But, both are in same folder, so why need to give folder name also?

Comment: Laravel uses `resources/views` as root folder for your views, not your current .blade.php location. Not really an explaination, but ... from [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views): "_Of course, views may also be nested within sub-directories of the resources/views directory. "Dot" notation may be used to reference nested views. For example, if your view is stored at resources/views/admin/profile.blade.php, you may reference it like so: `return view('admin.profile', $data);`_"

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: HI.   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('front_view/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"> are not working in head.blade.php

Comment: That looks like it belongs to a different question, create a new one please, thx.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much